# Python: kivy installation error, not a git repository

Tags: python, kivy

Hy to everybody,
I have installed on my PC (Windows 10 Pro - 64 bit) Python, version 3.8.2 - 64 bit. Now, I want to try to create a GUI, using kivy, because it seems is good and it is open source. So, I'm trying to install it, and I'm following the official guide, on https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist. I'm at step 3, and previous steps were successful. Now, I have to digit the command:

```
python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
```

But it not works, and the prompt, that I'm using to install kivy, return the following list of error:

```
    Collecting kivy==1.11.1
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\marco\\Tools\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qbyepev_\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\marco\\Tools\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qbyepev_\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\marco\Tools\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qbyepev_\kivy\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\marco\Tools\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qbyepev_\kivy\
    Complete output (395 lines):
    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\marco\\Tools\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-ac_830t1\\cython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\marco\\Tools\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-ac_830t1\\cython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\marco\Tools\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-kukk6vm2'
           cwd: C:\Users\marco\Tools\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ac_830t1\cython\
      Complete output (321 lines):
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      copying cython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\CodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Coverage.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Debugging.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Shadow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\StringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\TestUtils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\BuildExecutable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Build
      ....
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pythread.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\slice.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bool.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_dict.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_exc.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_function.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_instance.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_int.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_long.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_method.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_module.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_number.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_object.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_ref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_type.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_version.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\errno.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\float.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\locale.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\math.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\setjmp.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stddef.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdint.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\time.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\algorithm.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\cast.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\deque.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\forward_list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\functional.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\list.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\memory.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\pair.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\queue.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\stack.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\string.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeindex.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeinfo.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_map.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_set.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\utility.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\vector.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      ....
      copying Cython\Utility\StringTools.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestUtilityLoader.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TypeConversion.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\arrayarray.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CppSupport.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Cython\Utility
      running build_ext
      building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
         subprocess.check_call(cmd)
       File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
     subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['D:\\Python\\Orbit_Project\\kivy_venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\marco\\Tools\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpx6a6oakm', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "C:\Users\marco\Tools\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qbyepev_\kivy\setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
       File "D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
       File "D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 138, in _install_setup_requires
         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
       File "D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 695, in fetch_build_eggs
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
       File "D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
         return installer(requirement)
       File "D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 754, in fetch_build_egg
         return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
       File "D:\Python\Orbit_Project\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
         raise DistutilsError(str(e))
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['D:\\Python\\Orbit_Project\\kivy_venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\marco\\Tools\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpx6a6oakm', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"Package gstreamer-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `gstreamer-1.0.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\r\nNo package 'gstreamer-1.0' found\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"Package gstreamer-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `gstreamer-1.0.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\r\nNo package 'gstreamer-1.0' found\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b"Package sdl2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `sdl2.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\r\nNo package 'sdl2' found\r\nPackage SDL2_ttf was not found in the pkg-config search path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_ttf.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\r\nNo package 'SDL2_ttf' found\r\nPackage SDL2_image was not found in the pkg-config search path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_image.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\r\nNo package 'SDL2_image' found\r\nPackage SDL2_mixer was not found in the pkg-config search path.\r\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `SDL2_mixer.pc'\r\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\r\nNo package 'SDL2_mixer' found\r\n"

    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I inserted dots because there were too much caracters in this post, and the deleted sentences are similar.
I installed python in C:\ directory, and I'm trying to install kivy inside my project, as the guide states.
Does anyone know this problem, and he knows how to resolve?
I found similar problems but solutions don't resolve my case.
Thank you very much in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to problem. Simply, Python 3.8.2 is not compatible with kivy, for the moment. I uninstalled it, and I installed Python 3.7.6. Now, it's working perfectly.

Comment: I wish Kivy would update their online documentation.